# Last paycheck not direct deposited

Tags: exit-planning, payroll

I left my previous job on good terms (two weeks notice, etc.). My last payday in the normal two-week cycle was earlier this week. However, I did not receive a direct deposit. Upon checking the payroll site, I see a paystub listing a physical check number rather than "Deposited to the account..", similar to the first paystub when I started with the company before direct deposit was setup. (At that time my manager hand-delivered my paycheck, but clearly that is not an option now.)

Is this normal? How long should I wait before contacting my former manager or HR representative?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is this normal?

Yes, some places will do this to ensure that all equipment/property is returned to them before your last check is issued.  They also do this so that any time off / sick time that was taken in between pay periods is accounted for. 
(*basically make sure you don't owe the company money or have any company equipment*)

> How long should I wait before contacting my former manager or HR
>   representative?

At this point you should call HR now, but as Joe mentioned in the comments I bet the check is in the mail.

Comment: However, they may be holding it until they have confirmation of something from you (such as returned equipment) so call today.

Comment: @HLGEM It showed up via carrier before I even called. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

> Is this normal ?

I'm guessing only your manager or HR knows.

> How long should you wait before contacting them ?

Thats up to you and how much this problem bothers you. I don't really see whats stopping you from checking up quickly now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is normal. Meaning it is not unheard of. I have run across enough companies that do this that it doesn't seem worrisome.

Sending by mail makes the most sense when the you were receiving a check each payday, and they were giving it to you in person. Now that you aren't in the office they need to send it to you.

I always though that people getting direct deposit would just get a direct deposit  for that last check. The last time I asked about this I was told that the checks were mailed because they needed to remove the time card from the normal workflow.

Even if your situation was for a full pay period, that isn't always the case. They need to calculate your payout of Vacation/Sick. They have to make sure that if you have a negative balance in your PTO that is accounted for. They have to verify that you don't owe them any money for a travel advance, or if you have to re-pay them for classes you attended or for moving expenses.

The last place I left gave me the option of mailing the check. This could be good if you are moving from the area and want it sent to your new address instead of a bank account you are closing.